# Add and return as list of long async

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i trying create a function that will create a array of long and return this, cuz i will be use inside another function.

```
    private async Task<List<long>> ReturnListArrayLong()
    {
        if (MemOpen())
        {
            byte[] bPosition = new byte[290];
            mmfvs.Read(bPosition, 0, 290);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bPosition, 0, data, 0, bPosition.Length);

            List<long> ArrayLong = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] != 0)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => ArrayLong.Add(data[i]));
                }
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
            return ArrayLong;
        }
    }

public async Task getArray()
{
    await ReturnListArrayLong();
}
```

[image]
eror: **DrawForm.ReturnListArrayLong()': not all code paths return a value**

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Comment: get a array long and add to a list<long> and return this.

Comment: Think you just need to use `Add()` instead of `AddRange()`, because you're only adding a single long to the list, not a series of longs. So `await Task.Run(() => ArrayPlayer.Add(data[i]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have return statement in wrong place, within `if` condition. Move declaration and return outside `if` and you should be good.

```
List<long> ArrayLong = new List<long>();
if (MemOpen())
        {
            byte[] bPosition = new byte[290];
            mmfvs.Read(bPosition, 0, 290);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bPosition, 0, data, 0, bPosition.Length);


            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] != 0)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => ArrayLong.Add(data[i]));
                }
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

        }
return ArrayLong;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The function is not defined with the correct return type.

`ArrayLong` should be `List<long>`, while you currently have it defined as `List<Task<long>>`

`data` appears to be a `long[]` so you need to call `Add(data[i])` on the list and not `AddRange` which expects an `IEnumerable<long>`

```
private async Task<List<long>> ReturnListArrayLong() {
    List<long> ArrayLong = new List<long>();
    if (MemOpen()) {
        byte[] bPosition = new byte[290];
        mmfvs.Read(bPosition, 0, 290);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bPosition, 0, data, 0, bPosition.Length);            
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
            if (data[i] != 0) {
                await Task.Run(() => ArrayLong.Add(data[i]));
            }
           await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
    return ArrayLong;
}
```

Also use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` in an async function.

Comment: thx, but i get same error in data[i] "cannot convert from 'long' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<long>>"

Comment: @CerraossoUC look at my code carefully. `ArrayLong` should be `List<long>`, you have `List<Task<long>>`

Comment: ok thx, but i get new error in name function: ReturnListArrayLong()': not all code paths return a value